# Would having two instances of the same Google Analytics code cause false data?

Tags: google-analytics

A client of mine is running a store through Shopify. I had hardcoded the Analytics code into the theme for them already, but not knowing that I had, they added the code into the Shopify backend as well(there's a setting in the backend where you can paste the code), so for the past few weeks there have been two instances of Google Analaytics on the site(using the same GA account). I have removed one now, but I was wondering if anyone knows if this would cause false reports or if one would just cancel the other out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, having two trackers using the same tracking id is going to affect your numbers. In some cases, the metrics will be doubled. For example, the pageviews should increase. The number of unique visitors will likely not change though. You'll also see slightly lower bounce rates, higher time on site, higher number of visits per session etc.

One of things you can do is: compare the period with double tagging with period where you had not double tagged(GA has a easy way of doing comparisons between two periods). You'll see a stark difference in the metrics that are affected.

Comment: Thanks Avi, I figured 12% bounce rate was low for this site :P Now, I'm off to crush my client's spirit. Cheers!